# Select or mark text in UITextView without it becoming first responder

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextview, first-responder

Is this even possible?

I want to select/mark text without text view becoming first responder. I have search implemented in `UIPopoverController` and then when it's dismissed `UIToolBar` with Next and Previous button is showed which allows me to select next or previous result and I see that text is being selected because UITextView scrolls down and up respectively but I don't see any selection color or text that's actually selected, just plain black on white.

If it is first responder than everything is working but that's not behavior that I'm trying to achieve.

Any hints?

Tnx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on iOS 6 environment, you can use the `attributedText` property if `UITextView`.

If you're working below iOS 6, try using [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView), it's a drop-in replacement with rich text editing, it haven't been supported for a year or so, so I don't really know if it'll work.

You should determine a range for which you'll apply the changes

```
NSRange range = [textView.text rangeOfString:searchString];
```

Then create the attributed string

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textView.text];
[attrStr addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor cyanColor] range:range];
textView.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Comment: While this can work, it doesn't work for me here. I'm planning to do code highlighting over `NSAttributedString` latter. If no one responds with some other workaround I will accept this answer. Thanks Eugene.